# How to fill up a textbox with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to javascript and I was trying to populate a textbox from html with javascript but for some reason isn't working. This is what I have:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Relations</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="kandi.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
  
  <script src="myscript.js"></script>
  
  <body>
 <h1 align="center" style="font-family:Arial;" >RELATION TAGGING </h1>
 <textarea id="your_textarea" rows="15" cols="160">
 </textarea>
  
  </body>
  </head>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById("your_textarea");
textarea.innerHTML = "testing123";
```

Comment: try with **textarea.innerHTML = ''testing123";**

Comment: Does it make a difference that I am running this from a seperate .js file? I am amending my post to show the full code

Comment: Yes it does, the input field does not exist at the point when your JS code is executed. Move the script to the end of body, or execute your code on page load. (Research the latter, if it doesn’t mean anything to you.)

Comment: Thanks made it work perfectly! :)

Answer (score 2):

Textareas are not text inputs. Whereas input elements store the input in an attribute: `<input value="foo">`, textareas get them as content: `<textarea>foo</textarea>`. Use this instead:

```
textarea.textContent = "testing123"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `value` property of the `<textarea>`

This will be consistent around `<input>` and `<select>` elements

I would prefer this approach over the `textContent` approach. It will continue to work, if you would change the textarea to a input.

```js
var textarea = document.getElementById("your_textarea");

textarea.value = "this text is added with JS"
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<h1>RELATION TAGGING</h1>
<textarea id="your_textarea" rows="15" cols="160"></textarea>
```